# Unit Test d3v4 zoom behavior in React with Chai

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, d3.js, svg, chai

Using d3v4, react and chai (chai-enzyme, chai-jquery) for unit testing.

So I have a zoom behavior attached to my graph.

```
const zoom = d3
  .zoom()
  .scaleExtent([1, Infinity])
  .on('zoom', () => {
    this.zoomed()
  })
```

And the zoom behavior is attached to the svg element.

```
const svg = d3
  .select(this.node)
  .select('svg')
  .attr('preserveAspectRatio', 'xMinYMin meet')
  .attr('viewBox', `0 0 ${svgWidth} ${svgHeight}`)
  .classed('svg-content-responsive', true)
  .select('g')
  .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`)
  .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .call(zoom)
```

The on('zoom') callback is defined as

```
zoomed () {
 const {gXAxis, plotPlanText, plotZones, width, xAxis, xScale} = this.graphObjects
 const transform = d3.event.transform

 // get xMin and xMax in the viewable world
 const [xMin, xMax] = xScale.domain().map(d => xScale(d))

 // Get reverse transform for xMin and xMax.
 if (transform.invertX(xMin) < 0) {
   transform.x = -xMin * transform.k
 }
 if (transform.invertX(xMax) > width) {
   transform.x = xMax - width * transform.k
 }

 // transform the bars for zones

 if (!isNaN(transform.x) && !isNaN(transform.y) && !isNaN(transform.k)) {
   // rescale the x linear scale so that we can draw the x axis
   const xNewScale = transform.rescaleX(xScale)
   xAxis.scale(xNewScale)

   // rescale xaxis
   gXAxis.call(xAxis)

   plotZones
     .selectAll('rect')
     .attr('x', (d, i) => transform.applyX(xScale(d.maxFrequency)))
     .attr('width', (d) => -(transform.applyX(xScale(d.maxFrequency)) - transform.applyX(xScale(d.minFrequency))))

   // transform  the flow text
   plotPlanText
     .selectAll('.plan-text-src')
     .attr('x', d => (transform.applyX(xScale(d.maxFrequency)) + transform.applyX(xScale(d.minFrequency))) / 2)
   plotPlanText
     .selectAll('.plan-text-dest')
     .attr('x', d => (transform.applyX(xScale(d.maxFrequency)) + transform.applyX(xScale(d.minFrequency))) / 2)
 }}
```

My unit test for firing up the "zoom" event is

```
describe('d3 Event handling', function () {
  beforeEach(function () {
    $.fn.triggerSVGEvent = function (eventName, delta) {
      let event = new Event(eventName, {'bubbles': true, 'cancelable': false})
      if (delta) {
        event.deltaX = delta.x
        event.deltaY = delta.y
      }
      this[0].dispatchEvent(event)
      return $(this)
    }
  })

  describe('When the chart is zoomed', function () {
    let initialX
    beforeEach(function () {
      $('.flow-zone-container > svg > g').triggerSVGEvent('wheel')
    })
    it('should update elements when zoomed', function () {
      ...
    })
  })
})
```

When I use chai-jquery to trigger the "wheel" event, the zoom event is fired but the d3.event.tranform in the zoomed() method gives NaN for x, y and k. I want to test the zoomed() callback such that I have the d3.event.transform values to test the logic in the zoomed() method.

How can I fire the zoomEvent using "wheel" event or any other event such that d3.event is fired with some values?

Answer (score 0):

Solved this. Instead of using the jquery to fire the event, I am now using `zoomBehaviour.scaleBy(selection, scale)` to fire the callback.